# Where to store objects if I want them to be accessible for every class in my project

Tags: c#, object

just like the tittle says. I've got few arrays, few lists and I need them to be accessible for every class in my program. Is that even possible? I'm in a hurry and I couldnt find the answer on the internet,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

**EDIT**

for example you can do this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string str="Str";
    ////
}

public class NewClass
{
    public static string newstr="New "+MyClass.str;
    ////
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class called `Global` or something similar, and put all the arrays and list as `static` public properties there. You can then access them as `Global.ArrayThis` or `Global.ListThat`

Comment: can I still change variables even tho they are static?

Comment: @Patryk if you don't want other classes change these variables values, use the `final` modifier

Comment: thanks for helping me guys, both Likurg and zmbq :P I'd accept 2 answers as a correct one but since it's impossible and likurg has less rep points, ill mark his answer

Comment: `final` is a Java modifier. In C# you just set it as a get-only property. You could use `readonly` but properties are better.